# RazorSQL, adding profile with Derby

Tags: derby, razorsql

I installed `Derby` with [this procedure](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html)

After installing, `ij` command is working and connection with DB is working.

And i want to look into the DB table with GUI, so i downloaded `RazorSQL`
But in the step of adding profile(like a below picture), I faced a problem.

It seems to require `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver` but anywhere i couldn't find this file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a file, but a class. That class is in derby.jar